# Wait for element change not present (WebDriver/JavaScript/Jest)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, javascript, jestjs

Yesterday I struggled with waiting for a loading indicator to be removed. Added this question and answer here because we spend a lot of time on it and Google didn't help much. Hopefully this will help others in the future. Still if you have a different or better solution to this problem please post your answer.

**Situation**:

We have a [dropdown build with Semantic-UI](http://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown). When we open the dropdown the dropdown starts loading the data. In the test we need to wait until the dropdown is fully loaded which takes random between 500-2000ms. Then we can process the test to select or retrieve the needed items.

Relevant version from package.json:

```
"semantic-ui": "^2.2.9",
"semantic-ui-react": "^0.66.0"
"jest": "^19.0.2",
"selenium-webdriver": "^3.3.0",
"chromedriver": "^2.29.0",
```

**Problem**:

Normally I would use the `until.elementIsNotVisible(element)` function to wait for the loading element to be not visible, but Semantic-UI does not remove the element it changes it to a 'V' dropdown-arrow icon by removing the `loading` class from the element. Thus the element stays visible it is just changed. Also I do not want to add a sleep for 3000ms.

To complicate it even more the loading image is added as content to a `::After` CSS part, which cannot be used in CSS or Xpath locators. You cannot check for elements based on it attributes this way.

The best way is to wait for `loading` class to be removed from the parent div and not check the image.

**Question**:

How do I detect class changes on elements with plain selenium-webdriver in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created my own `isNotPresent` wait-until method which uses a locator so you can check if an element with a certain class is not present anymore. This loops over the locator either until the timeout is reached or no elements with that locator are present.

```
import webdriver from 'selenium-webdriver';   

export default class Element {
  static defaultTimeOut() { return 30000; }

  // other helper methods ...

  static async isNotPresent(driver, locator) {
    await driver.wait(() => {
      return driver.findElements(locator).then((elements) => {
        if (elements.length <= 0) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      });
    }, Element.defaultTimeOut(), 'The element was still present when it should have disappeared.');
  }
}
```

Example implementation code parts to showcase usage:

```
import Element from '../Util/WaitForElements';

async waitUntilFiltersLoaded() {
  await Element.isNotPresent(this.driver, By.css('.filterPanel .loading'));
}
```